# Text Node Selector within single td using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cheerio

I need to extract the text after Name:, Phone:, Email:, Lead Submitted:, Comments:, Property Address 1:

The problem is all these text nodes are siblings. I don't know how to choose a sibling by number if it's a text node - e.g. the top sibling is a span but the rest are text nodes. I have tried different iterations but the only thing I'm getting to work is
var comments = $('span:contains("Renter's Information")').siblings().text().trim();
But this pulls all the text, not just the comments text. Ideally I'd like to get not just each text node but the text after 'Name:', 'Phone:' etc. but I will probably have to trim that off post jQuery though. Any guidance on pulling these individual text nodes would be appreciated.

```
<td align="left" style="font-family:'Lucida Grande','Lucida Sans Unicode','Lucida Sans','DejaVu Sans',Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#666;padding:24px">
<span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;color:#333">Renter's Information</span>
<br> Name: Shelby 
<br> Phone: <a href="tel:(555)%25555-5555" style="color:#666;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">(555) 555-555</a>
<br> Email: <a href="mailto:email@gmail.com" style="color:#666;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">email@gmail.com</a>
<br> Lead Submitted: 9/13/2020 1:42:37 PM
<br>
<br> <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;color:#333">Renter's Preferences</span>
<br> Beds/Baths:
<br> Model:
<br> Unit:
<br>
<br> Move Date: 11/2/2020
<br> Comments: Hi there! Just came across your listing online. I was wondering if you could send us some updated photos and financial information, as in if anything is included in cost, how much the house needs paid off &amp; just some details so we can look to see if we want to check it out. Thank you!
<br>
<br> <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;color:#333">Property Information</span>
<br> Link: <a href="https://www.apartments.com/" style="color:#77b800;text-decoration:none" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=">https://www.apartments.com/</a>
<br> To: <a href="#m_7_" style="color:#666;text-decoration:none">property</a>
<br> Property Address 1: <a href="#m_7654125587635847623_" style="color:#666;text-decoration:none">property</a>
<br> Property Address 2: <a href="#m_7654125587635847623_" style="color:#666;text-decoration:none"></a>
<br> City: city
<br> State: NY
<br> Zip: 12345
<br>
<br> <span style="font-weight:bold">Wishing you success in converting this True Lead™ to a lease!</span>
<br> <span style="font-weight:bold">The <a href="https://www.apartments.com/customers" style="color:#666;text-decoration:none" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://www.apartments.com/customers&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1603510777154000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHUYM0naErXYLjI9u_P_I4jk9Xtfg">Apartments.com Network</a> Team</span>
</td>
```

Comment: If you just need text, reading `innerText` attribute on `<td>` should be helpful to you.

Comment: This is definitely the kind of thing you want to regex for instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood from your question that you want to get some text according to some keywords in your HTML, here is an implementation for that!
and I have edited my answer to store the content in an array instead of logging them on the fly

```js
// the words you search for, note that in this solution they need to be ordered
// just to avoid nested for loops that leads to larger time complexity
let searchKeywords = ["Name", "Phone", "Email", "Lead Submitted", "Comments", "Property Address 1"];
            
function getTextContent(keywords, htmlContent) {
  // an array to store in the content
  let arr = [];
  // since there is a <br> element before each span element that makes it
  // easy to just get the html and split it into lines
  htmlContent.split("<br>").forEach(function(e) {
    if(e.startsWith(` ${searchKeywords[arr.length]}`)) {
      // if the current line starts with the current keyword then if it has an
      // <a> tag then get the text of it, otherwise just slice the keyword name
      arr.push((e.includes("<a") ? e.substring(e.indexOf(">") + 1, e.indexOf("</a>")) : e.slice(e.indexOf(":") + 1)).trim());
    }
  });
  return arr;
}

let result = getTextContent(searchKeywords, document.querySelector("td").innerHTML);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" style="font-family:'Lucida Grande','Lucida Sans Unicode','Lucida Sans','DejaVu Sans',Verdana,sans-serif;font-size:14px;color:#666;padding:24px">
      <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;color:#333">Renter's Information</span>
      <br> Name: Shelby 
      <br> Phone: <a href="tel:(555)%25555-5555" style="color:#666;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">(555) 555-555</a>
      <br> Email: <a href="mailto:email@gmail.com" style="color:#666;text-decoration:none" target="_blank">email@gmail.com</a>
      <br> Lead Submitted: 9/13/2020 1:42:37 PM
      <br>
      <br> <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;color:#333">Renter's Preferences</span>
      <br> Beds/Baths:
      <br> Model:
      <br> Unit:
      <br>
      <br> Move Date: 11/2/2020
      <br> Comments: Hi there! Just came across your listing online. I was wondering if you could send us some updated photos and financial information, as in if anything is included in cost, how much the house needs paid off &amp; just some details so we can look to see if we want to check it out. Thank you!
      <br>
      <br> <span style="font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;color:#333">Property Information</span>
      <br> Link: <a href="https://www.apartments.com/" style="color:#77b800;text-decoration:none" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=">https://www.apartments.com/</a>
      <br> To: <a href="#m_7_" style="color:#666;text-decoration:none">property</a>
      <br> Property Address 1: <a href="#m_7654125587635847623_" style="color:#666;text-decoration:none">property</a>
      <br> Property Address 2: <a href="#m_7654125587635847623_" style="color:#666;text-decoration:none"></a>
      <br> City: city
      <br> State: NY
      <br> Zip: 12345
      <br>
      <br> <span style="font-weight:bold">Wishing you success in converting this True Lead™ to a lease!</span>
      <br> <span style="font-weight:bold">The <a href="https://www.apartments.com/customers" style="color:#666;text-decoration:none" target="_blank" data-saferedirecturl="https://www.google.com/url?hl=en&amp;q=https://www.apartments.com/customers&amp;source=gmail&amp;ust=1603510777154000&amp;usg=AFQjCNHUYM0naErXYLjI9u_P_I4jk9Xtfg">Apartments.com Network</a> Team</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And for your comment:

> The above HTML is part of a much larger section of HTML so to locate the td I'd have to search for the text "Renter's Information" and then from there I can implement the script you recommended

Well you can filter the span elements to get the one that has the text content `"Renter's Information"`
and then get its parent element which will be the `td` element you are looking for, here is the code

```
let tdElement = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("span"), function(e) {
  return e.textContent === "Renter's Information";
})[0].parentElement;
```

And then get your content by calling `getTextContent()` like this

```
let result = getTextContent(searchKeywords, tdElement.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm parsing the HTML from an email I receive using jQuery - I don't have control over the format of the info so I have to work with what it is. The above HTML is part of a much larger section of HTML so to locate the `td` I'd have to search for the text `"Renter's Information"` and then from there I can implement the script you recommended. What would be the best way to first pull out just this `td` section of HTML? `var html = $('td:contains("Renter\'s Information")')` ?

Comment: Also instead of saving to consol.log, if I wanted to add each text item to an array, would this be the best way? `array.push([(e.includes("<a") ? e.substring(e.indexOf(">") + 1, e.indexOf("</a>")) : e.slice(e.indexOf(":") + 1)).trim()][i]);`

Comment: @823g4n8901 I'm sorry for the late reply, I was working, I have updated my answer, check it out